# How to change parameters htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to change url parameters using .httacess , i am not too much familiar with complex httacess thats why i need help regarding this .

`http://www.gardeningwithangus.com.au/index.php?option=com_plant&view=plant&botanic-name=Wahlenbergia&cultivar=Sky Mist&common-name=Native Bluebell&plant-id=`

need to change plant-id to id. So url will some thing like that
`index.php?option=com_plant&view=plant&botanic-name=Wahlenbergia&cultivar=Sky Mist&common-name=Native Bluebell&id=`

Same with 
`http://www.gardeningwithangus.com.au/plants?view=plant&botanic-name=Crowea+exalata&cultivar=Low+Dome&common-name=Crowea&plant-id=`

Any help please.. !

My Code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(view=plant)&plant-id=([0-9]*)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(component/plant)/?$ /$1/?%1&id=%2 [L,NC,R=301]

##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(option=.+?)&plant-id=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)$ $1?%1&id=%2 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(view=.+?)&plant-id=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(plants)$ $1?%1&id=%2 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Seems like a job for mod_rewrite. I don't know much about it but it's a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming query parameters are in the given order as the question.*

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` (if not already enabled) and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(option=.+?)&plant-id=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)$ $1?%1&id=%2 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(view=.+?)&plant-id=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(plants|component/plant)/?$ $1?%1&id=%2 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: 1st link is working like a charm, but second one is not working !

Comment: Yes but i need to same like 1st 
I just tested 2nd link also and it became: /index.php?option=com_plant&view=plant&botanic-name=Wahlenbergia&cultivar=Sky Mist&common-name=Native Bluebell&id=

Comment: like remove word plant- from the last of link

Comment: 2nd link became: `/index.php?option=com_plant&view=plant&botanic-name=Wahlenbergia&cultivar=Sky%2520Mist&common-name=Native%2520Bluebell&id=` transforming `plant-id` to `id`

Comment: http://www.gardeningwithangus.com.au/plants?view=plant&botanic-name=Crowea+exalata&cultivar=Low+Dome&common-name=Crowea&plant-id=1211

Comment: I have tested and it worked. Can you paste your latest .htaccess code in question.

Comment: It became: `/plants?view=plant&botanic-name=Crowea+exalata&cultivar=Low+Dome&common-name=Crowea&id=1211`

Comment: Code Edited in Question

Comment: Why did you change to: `RewriteRule ^(component/plant)/?$`

Comment: Just after `RewriteEngine On` line on top you have that

Comment: Make sure to move these 2 rules to the top just after `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: This was another redirect for link

Comment: /component/plant/?view=plant&plant-id=477 to /component/plant/?view=plant&id=477

Comment: OK np, as I said move my suggested rules to the top.

Comment: So this will work too ?  
/component/plant/?view=plant&plant-id=477 to /component/plant/?view=plant&id=477

Comment: yes it will and this rule can be combined into 1 with plants URI

Comment: so you mean just delete two top lines and only paste your 4 lines right?

Comment: Take the latest edit and place it at top then delete your `component/plant` rule and may I request to do it quick since it is extremely late here.

Comment: I have already edited code in my answer. Place it on top of your .htaccess where `RewriteEngine On`